# how to use the implode effect from wand(python) from another position (not the middle of the image)?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

hey I've been using this code to use the implode effect from wand on images:

```
with Image(filename=img_path) as img:
    img.virtual_pixel = 'black'
    img.implode(0.5)
    img.save(filename="bulged.jpg")
```

the only problem I have is that effect take default position in the center of the image and I can't change it.
anyone knows a way around this or how to change it ?

Comment: There is no argument for moving the implode point. However, you can use roll to roll the image around to move the center position. Then after the implode roll it back. Alternately, use distort SRT with a filter of point to shift the image, implode, then shift back. Unfortunately, I do not see roll in the list of image methods in Wand, nor do I see how to use filter=point in distort SRT. So we will need to wait for Eric McConville (the Wand maintainer/developer) to respond. Perhaps they have different names in Wand or it was an oversight in Wand and they are missing

Answer (score 1):

As [fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7355741/fmw42) pointed out in the comments. Using `Image.roll()` method to move pixels around may allow you to position the target pixels at the center of the image, apply `Image.implode()`, then return pixels back.

> Unfortunately, I do not see roll in the list of image methods in Wand[.]

This is correct. The method is simply missing from Wand. We can still use the C-API method directly, but need to do some extra work to ensure exceptions are checked.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

with Image(filename='wizard:') as img:
    # Grab image size
    cols, rows = img.size
    # Define our target location ... say 1/3rd, by 1/5th
    tx, ty = int(cols * 0.33), int(rows * 0.2)
    # Find middle of the image.
    mx, my = cols // 2, rows // 2
    # Roll target coord into middle
    ok = library.MagickRollImage(img.wand, mx-tx, my-ty)
    if not ok:
        img.raise_exception()
    # Implode
    img.implode(0.5)
    # Roll middle back into place.
    ok = library.MagickRollImage(img.wand, mx+tx, my+ty)
    if not ok:
        img.raise_exception()
    # done
    img.save(filename='output.png')
```

[image: output.png]

**Update**

Using SRT (scale-rotate-translate) distortion can also work. However you'll need to define some additional options to adjust the behavior.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='wizard:') as img:
    # Grab image size
    cols, rows = img.size
    # Define our target location ... say 1/3rd, by 1/5th
    tx, ty = int(cols * 0.33), int(rows * 0.2)
    # Find middle of the image.
    mx, my = cols // 2, rows // 2
    img.options['filter'] = 'point'
    # Increase viewpoint to allow pixels to move out-of-bounds.
    viewport = '{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(tx*2+cols, ty*2+rows, tx, ty)
    img.options['distort:viewpoint'] = viewport
    img.virtual_pixel = 'tile'
    # Distort target coords to middle of image.
    img.distort(method='scale_rotate_translate',
                arguments=[tx, ty, 1, 0, mx, my])
    # Implode
    img.implode(0.5)
    # Distort middle back into place.
    img.distort(method='scale_rotate_translate',
                arguments=[mx, my, 1, 0, tx, ty])
    # Restore original image size.
    img.extent(width=cols, height=rows)
    # done
    img.save(filename='output.png')
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: Eric, one should also be able to do this with distort(method=SRT) and no scale and no rotation, but with the filter set to point.  Can you show how to do this, also?

Comment: Surething Fred. However, the SRT method is generating some unwanted `Edge` artifacts. Perhaps you can share a CLI distort solution, and I can re-write with Wand.

Comment: `@EricMcConville`, you need to specify the virtual-pixel to say white. The default is edge which just repeats the edge of the image. If that does not work, email me and I will compose the command line solution for you.

Comment: @fmw42 Update! Looks like `-virtual-pixel Tile` was the option I needed.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was not expecting that.